# working with list of list using python

Tags: python, list

I am working on list using python

input :

```
[[u'Tempoh', '', '', u'Belanjawan semasa', '', '', u'Perbelanjaan pembangunan', '', '', u'Lebihan / kurangan(-) keseluruhan', u'Sumber-sumber kewangan', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', u'Current budget', '', '', u'Development expenditure', '', '', '', u'Sources of finance', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', u'Hasil', u'Perbelanjaan1', u'Lebihan / kurangan(-)', u'Perbelanjaan pembangunan kasar', u'Tolak: Terimaan balik pinjaman', u'Perbelanjaan pembangunan bersih', '', u'Pinjaman dalam negeri', '', '', u'Pinjaman luar negeri', '', '', u'Penggunaan harta2'], ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', u'Domestic borrowing', '', '', u'Foreign borrowing', '', '', ''], [u'Period', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', u'Peminjaman kasar dalam negeri', u'Tolak: Pembayaran balik dalam negeri', u'Peminjaman bersih dalam negeri', u'Peminjaman kasar luar negeri', u'Tolak: Pembayaran balik luar negeri', u'Peminjaman bersih luar negeri', ''], ['', '', '', u'Revenue', u'Expenditure1', u'Surplus / deficit(-)', u'Gross development expenditure', u'Less: Loan recoveries', u'Net development expenditure', u'Overall surplus / deficit(-)', u'Gross domestic borrowing', u'Less: Domestic repayment', u'Net domestic borrowing', u'Gross foreign borrowing', u'Less: Foreign repayment', u'Net foreign borrowing', u'Use of assets']
```

output:

I want this empty space to be filled by previous string

thanks in advance

Comment: This list contains some nested lists, do you want to chain the list together so it is one list? Or do you want to only have empty spaces filled inside the nested lists?

Comment: When you say previous string, does the previous string have to be non-empty?

Comment: This appears to some English/Malay translations. I don't understand what you need for the output though. Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following idiom:

```
new = [s2 or s1 for s1, s2 in zip (stringList, stringList[1:])] # + last element
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `s1 if not s2 else s1`? That returns `s1` no matter what.

Comment: It is a typo, fixed now.

Comment: I think you could also do  this with the following code: s2 or s1

Comment: Thanks, every time I forget this form.